# How to find list of available packages for preseed pkgsel/include list?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, preseed, debian-installer

When setting up a preseed file for a particular Ubuntu release, how can one find out what are legal values to use in a pkgsel/include list? I have a long list of packages to install for this application, and I would like to know which ones can be installed via the preseed file.

The specific context for my question is installing Ubuntu 18.04 desktop from an ISO file using Packer, but the question is intended to be more general.

Comment: I think everything from the enabled repos at that point should be OK for use. Did you have some problem with those?

Comment: I have no visibility into the installer under Packer. So it's a blind trial-and-error process.

Comment: You want something like https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages ?  Packages are just being installed with apt.  There isn't anything special going on.  Unless you are thinking of `tasksel` instead of `pkgsel`.

Comment: I don't recall seeing that documented anywhere, although it makes perfect sense. Thanks.